# Is there any way to make a object read only outside the class?

Tags: java, class, object, readonly

So lets say I have a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int myInt = 5;
}
```

Now I don't want this to happen:

```
MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
myObject.myInt = 10;
```

I just want "myInt" to be read only. How can I do that?

Comment: Make it private and just supply a getter

Answer (score 4):

`I just want "myInt" to be read only` make it `final`

```
public class MyClass
{
    public final int myInt = 5;
}
```

or `private` and add getter method

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int myInt = 5;

    public int getMyInt(){
       return myInt;
    }
}
```

Both solutions have pros but also cons:

- final will make it read only also inside class,
- private wont guarantee that it wont be changed with `reflection`.

Comment: What do you mean "changed with reflection"?

Comment: @seedasharp `Class` class have method `getDeclaredField` that returns `Field` object. Field have method `setAccessible()` and if you invoke it with `true` it will let access to this field. Field have also `set` method which can be used to change value of filed in some object. Take a look at this example http://ideone.com/QFHqox

Answer (score 2):

Use `private` to make it inaccessible, or make it `final` to make it immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Make the variable private and add a getter method.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int myInt = 5;

    public int getMyInt(){
      return this.myInt;
    }
}

MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
myObject.getMyInt();    //This will return 5
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to do this. Make myInt private and declare a public getter function. What are you trying to accomplish?

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int myInt = 5;

    public int getInt() { return myInt; }
}
```